# Deleted documents not replicated in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

We had a replica set running and accidentally deleted some documents. We added another member to the set with `hidden = true` and `slaveDelay = 3600`. When the sync completed for the member, we were unable to find the deleted documents in the slave (queried on the console after running `rs.slaveOk()`) even though an hour had not passed since deleting the docs. Can anyone provide a possible explanation for our observation? Are deleted documents not replicated using oplogs in this case? We were on v3.2.10 for the initial set and v3.4.* for the new member.

Comment: Why would you expect to find the documents copied to the secondary, after they have been deleted?

Comment: I was assuming that all replication occurs using the oplogs - in which case those documents would still be available on the lagging secondary.

Answer (score 0):

The initial replication does not use oplogs but clones the collections from another member of the replicaset https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-initial-sync. After the initial sync, oplogs are used.